# What happens to ExecutorService if I stop a running java project

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

While I'm testing my code in Eclipse, I stopped the program in the console, but I found the threads still keep working. I'm trying to create a pipeline to precess for our continuously incoming data. How can I shut down all the running threads when I stop the program?

(Especially when I am using a infinite loop )

Here is my main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<StreamQueueItem>(100);       

    LogFileProcessor threadFileProcessor = new LogFileProcessor(queue);
    new Thread(threadFileProcessor).start();

    StreamCoordinator threadStreamCoordinator = new StreamCoordinator(queue);
    new Thread(threadStreamCoordinator).start();

}
```

Basically first thread is keeping enqueue the BlockingQueue, and the second Thread is keeping pop items out of the queue, and pick a request sender to send a request.

The code of StreamCoordinator:

```
public StreamCoordinator(BlockingQueue<StreamQueueItem> mQueue) {
    super();
    this.mQueue = mQueue;
    this.mThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ConfigConstants.SENDER_THREDPOOL_SIZE); 
    mBqHelper = new BigqueryHelper(ConfigConstants.PROJECT_ID,ConfigConstants.DATA_SET, ConfigConstants.TABLE_EXISTS);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    StreamQueueItem item = null;

    while(true){
        //wait 1 second for next request
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        item = mQueue.poll();
        if( item != null){
            mThreadPool.execute(new RequestSender(mBqHelper,item));
        }
    }

}
```

RequestSender:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.format("%d is sending request %s . List size: %d %s\n",mSenderId,FormatHelper.currentDate(),mRequestItem.getRowList().size(),mRequestItem.getLogReason().getTableName());
    mBqHelper.submitStreamRequest(mRequestItem.getLogReason().getTableName(), mRequestItem.getRowList());
    System.out.println("# " + mSenderId + " done. " + FormatHelper.currentDate());
}
```

Comment: "stop a java project"? That need's some clarification.

Comment: If you killed the JVM, there is no way the threads are still running.

Comment: I just clicked stop in the Eclipse console. May JVM is not killed because Eclipse is still open

Comment: I feel there should be something wrong with my code because I didn't info JVM that those running threads which called by mThreadPool should be stopped. But I've no idea where exactly the problem is.

Comment: “But I've no idea where exactly the problem is.” Neither do we.

Comment: You stopped the program by hitting the red button in eclipse and it continues to run? I find that unlikely, even using executorservice

Answer (score 0):

This is evil code:

```
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you catch an `InterruptedException`, you *must* handle it properly. Logging it and ignoring it will result in your program misbehaving. That exception is the runtime's way if telling your thread that it needs to stop (i.e. you pushed the red button).

Try reacting appropriately to the exception:

```
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    return;
}
```

This is an excellent article on the subject, well worth a read: [Java theory and practice: Dealing with InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/)